# How to prevent Vuetify navigation drawer from collapsing when a menu inside of it is hovered?

Tags: vuetify.js

I have a navigation drawer that expand on hover. But It collapses when I hover a menu that's inside of it. How can I keep the drawer from collapsing?

Here is the [component](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

[image]

[image]